# module import path mapping in VSCode without interacting with TypeScript configuration?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on a monorepo with multiple packages.

Imagine I have two libraries `a` and `b`. If inside `b` I import `a` using:

```
import a from '@org/a'
```

During compilation, the above path would be resolved by webpack (or yarn workspaces) to `../a`, where the `package.json` will instruct node to find `a/dist/index.js`.

During development, I want to map `@org/a` to `../a/src/index.ts` so intellisense will send me to the source folder rather than the build folder.

TypeScript includes the `paths` option in it's `tsconfig.json` which I can use inside `b` by mapping:

```
{
  "paths" {
    "@org/a": ["../a/src"]
  }
}
```

This works well in my IDE however, when using tsconfig paths, `b` emits `a`'s types in it's `build` folder when compiled - like so:

```
/src
  /a
    /build
      index.d.ts
      index.js
    index.ts
  /b
    /build
      /a
        index.d.ts
      /b
        index.d.ts
      index.js
    index.ts
```

For comparison, without including the tsconfig path configuration inside `b`, this is what `b`'s `build` folder looks like:

```
/b
  /build
    index.d.ts
    index.js
  index.ts
```

Using tsconfig paths results in the inclusion of files I don't want in my project and breaks the `types` key in `b`'s `package.json`

Is there a way I can manually configure vscode to map import paths rather than looking to the tsconfig for that information?